# HTML sibling selector not working when class is behind the target

Tags: html, css

html:

```
<div class="wraper">
  <div class="box">  
    <span class="text">Test2</span>
    <span class="loser text">Test1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span class="text">Test1</span>
    <span class="text">Test2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <span class="loser">Test1</span>
    <span class="text">Test2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wraper .loser ~ .text {
  color: pink;
}
```

The sibling selector only gets applied when the class targeted is in front of the div. Shouldn't it be applied regardless of the span ordering?

What I am trying to achieve is to always color the spans in the box that contains a loser class.

Codepen if you want to play around:
http://codepen.io/shooshte/pen/grxJpZ

Comment: `a ~ b`  selector means that it will target all `b` elements that appears **after** `a` elements and are siblings, so your codepen is working perfectly

Comment: This works as it's expected, but you didn't specify what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the ordering is not irrelevant. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) for the docs in MDN

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is **preceded** by the first, and both share a common
>   parent.

Comment: is there an alternative for what I want to do with CSS?

Comment: You didn't tell us yet what you want to achieve :)

Comment: Sorry, edited out the main question

Answer (score 0):

> The sibling selector only gets applied when the class targeted is in front of the div. Shouldn't it be applied regardless of the span ordering?

No, from [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators):

> and the element represented by the first sequence **precedes** (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the second one

CSS is designed so that after the parser has added an element to the DOM it knows *all* the rules that will be applied to that element. This prevents having to wait for the entire document to be parsed before it can tell which rules apply to an element.

Comment: is there an alternative for what I want to do with CSS?

Comment: No. Change the HTML. Add a class on a parent element.